# Tesseract OCR simple example

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

Hi Can you anyone give me a simple example of testing Tesseract OCR
preferably in C#.
I tried the demo found [here](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/).
I download the English dataset and unzipped in C drive. and modified the code as followings:

```
string path = @"C:\pic\mytext.jpg";
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path);
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); // If digit only
ocr.Init(@"C:\tessdata\", "eng", false); // To use correct tessdata
List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't work. the program dies at "ocr.Init(..." line. I couldn't even get an exception even using try-catch.

I was able to run the [vietocr](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/)! but that is a very large project for me to follow. i need a simple example like above.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work", does it crash or just not do what you want?

Comment: well, the program just close without any error or exception. nether it write output to the console. so i did dubbing and proceed line by line. and found that the program exits at line 5   -> ocr.Init(@"C:\tessdata\", "eng", false);

Comment: You can step into the function and find out what's causing the program to exit.

Comment: Is it possible a permission issue to load the tessdata under C disk? May change the path and try again.

Comment: the function is in the tessnet dll. I can't step into it! its a windows 7 machine i'm logged in as administrator. I don't see why there would be a permission problem. I don't even have another drive

Answer (score 21):

Ok. I found the solution here
[tessnet2 fails to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053575/tessnet2-fails-to-load)
the Ans given by Adam

Apparently i was using wrong version of tessdata. I was following the [the source page](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) instruction intuitively and that caused the problem.

it says

> Quick Tessnet2 usage
>
> 1. [Download binary here](http://tmp.m4f.eu/tessnet2.zip), add a reference of the assembly Tessnet2.dll to your .NET project.
> 2. Download language data definition file [here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list) and put it in tessdata directory. Tessdata directory and your exe must be in the
>    same directory.

After you download the binary, when you follow the link to download the language file, there are many language files. but none of them are right version. you need to select all version and go to next page for correct version (tesseract-2.00.eng)! They should either update download binary link to version 3 or put the the version 2 language file on the first page. Or at least bold mention the fact that this version issue is a big deal!

Anyway I found it.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: @ Will Robinson,The same problem is coming for me also.I have tried your above procedure...But still have same problem that u had faced.. First, I have downloaded binary from your link and extracted in my desktop.Then add the reference of the tessnet2_32.dll file from Release32 folder.Second, I have downloaded the LDD file from your link and also extracted the file in my desktop.It has one directory named as tessdata and put it in my project bin\debug folder(My Project exe is also in this foler).But the same problem am facing till now...Could please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: did you try downloading the right version of tessdata? tesseract-2.00.eng is on the second page all the way end of the list.

Comment: @Will Robinson: My VS is 2008, Windows XP (32bits). I followed your instructions and it didn't work. It runs to this line "tessocr.Init...", and then VS stops the execution without any error message nor exception. As a workaround I have downloaded a version of tesseract-3.00 (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz&can=2&q=) that comes with English language package included.

Answer (score 15):

A simple example of testing Tesseract OCR in C#:

```
    public static string GetText(Bitmap imgsource)
    {
        var ocrtext = string.Empty;
        using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
        {
            using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(imgsource))
            {
                using (var page = engine.Process(img))
                {
                    ocrtext = page.GetText();
                }
            }
        }

        return ocrtext;
    }
```

Info: The **tessdata** folder must exist in the repository: bin\Debug\

Comment: I ran this code and it says "Failed to find library \"liblept172.dll\" for platform x86." when debugging. The error occurs at the first using statement. I have found liblept172.ddl and copied it to the bin folder, in fact I copied to many places to no avail. I am using Tesseract v3.0.2 from NuGet. I can't find tessnet2 as all link on the internet to it seem to be broken.

Comment: What is `PixConverter` here? There does not seem to be any class with such name in `Tesseract` package.

Comment: here it is: https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/blob/master/src/Tesseract/PixConverter.cs

Comment: I was unable to get it to run like this, too, but I changed the PixConverter part to `using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imgsource))` and now it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get it to work by following these [instructions](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract#getting-started-quickly).

- Download the [sample code](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-samples)
  [image: Tesseract sample code]
- Unzip it to a new location
- Open ~\tesseract-samples-master\src\Tesseract.Samples.sln (I used Visual Studio 2017)
- Install the Tesseract NuGet package for that project (or uninstall/reinstall as I had to)
  [image: NuGet Tesseract]
- Uncomment the last two meaningful lines in Tesseract.Samples.Program.cs:
  `Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
  Console.ReadKey(true);`
- Run (hit F5)
- You should get this windows console output
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the line to:

ocr.Init(@"C:\", "eng", false); // the path here should be the parent folder of tessdata

Comment: Just tired that. still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, now its resolved. I have tesseract2, under this folders for 32 bit and 64 bit, I copied files 64 bit folder(as my system is 64 bit) to main folder ("Tesseract2") and under bin/Debug folder. Now my solution is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I had 3-4 more PDF to Text extractor and if one doesnot work the other one will ... tesseract in particular this code can be used on Windows 7, 8, Server 2008 . Hope this is helpful to you

```
    do
    {
    // Sleep or Pause the Thread for 1 sec, if service is running too fast...
    Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout: 1000);
    Guid tempGuid = ToSeqGuid();
    string newFileName = tempGuid.ToString().Split('-')[0];
    string outputFileName = appPath + "\\pdf2png\\" + fileNameithoutExtension + "-" + newFileName +
                            ".png";
    extractor.SaveCurrentImageToFile(outputFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
    // Create text file here using Tesseract
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(appPath + "\\pdf2png"))
    {
        try
        {
            var pngFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            string[] myArguments =
            {
                "/C tesseract ", file,
                " " + appPath + "\\png2text\\" + pngFileName
            }; // /C for closing process automatically whent completes
            string strParam = String.Join(" ", myArguments);

            var myCmdProcess = new Process();
            var theProcess = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", strParam)
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
            }; // Keep the cmd.exe window minimized
            myCmdProcess.StartInfo = theProcess;
            myCmdProcess.Exited += myCmdProcess_Exited;
            myCmdProcess.Start();

            //if (process)
            {
                /*
                MessageBox.Show("cmd.exe process started: " + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Process Name: " + myCmdProcess.ProcessName +
                                Environment.NewLine + " Process Id: " + myCmdProcess.Id
                                + Environment.NewLine + "process.Handle: " +
                                myCmdProcess.Handle);
                */
                Process.EnterDebugMode();
                //ShowWindow(hWnd: process.Handle, nCmdShow: 2);
                /*
                MessageBox.Show("After EnterDebugMode() cmd.exe process Exited: " +
                                Environment.NewLine +
                                "Process Name: " + myCmdProcess.ProcessName +
                                Environment.NewLine + " Process Id: " + myCmdProcess.Id
                                + Environment.NewLine + "process.Handle: " +
                                myCmdProcess.Handle);
                */
                myCmdProcess.WaitForExit(60000);
                /*
                MessageBox.Show("After WaitForExit() cmd.exe process Exited: " +
                                Environment.NewLine +
                                "Process Name: " + myCmdProcess.ProcessName +
                                Environment.NewLine + " Process Id: " + myCmdProcess.Id
                                + Environment.NewLine + "process.Handle: " +
                                myCmdProcess.Handle);
                */
                myCmdProcess.Refresh();
                Process.LeaveDebugMode();
                //myCmdProcess.Dispose();
                /*
                MessageBox.Show("After LeaveDebugMode() cmd.exe process Exited: " +
                                Environment.NewLine);
                */
            }


            //process.Kill();
            // Waits for the process to complete task and exites automatically
            Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout: 1000);

            // This works fine in Windows 7 Environment, and not in Windows 8
            // Try following code block
            // Check, if process is not comletey exited

            if (!myCmdProcess.HasExited)
            {
                //process.WaitForExit(2000); // Try to wait for exit 2 more seconds
                /*
                MessageBox.Show(" Process of cmd.exe was exited by WaitForExit(); Method " +
                                Environment.NewLine);
                */
                try
                {
                    // If not, then Kill the process
                    myCmdProcess.Kill();
                    //myCmdProcess.Dispose();
                    //if (!myCmdProcess.HasExited)
                    //{
                    //    myCmdProcess.Kill();
                    //}

                    MessageBox.Show(" Process of cmd.exe exited ( Killed ) successfully " +
                                    Environment.NewLine);
                }
                catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        " Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception " +
                        ex.ErrorCode + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException notSupporEx)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Exception: NotSupportedException " +
                                    notSupporEx.Message +
                                    Environment.NewLine);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOperation)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        " Exception: InvalidOperationException " +
                        invalidOperation.Message + Environment.NewLine);
                    foreach (
                        var textFile in Directory.GetFiles(appPath + "\\png2text", "*.txt",
                            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {
                        loggingInfo += textFile +
                                       " In Reading Text from generated text file by Tesseract " +
                                       Environment.NewLine;
                        strBldr.Append(File.ReadAllText(textFile));
                    }
                    // Delete text file after reading text here
                    Directory.GetFiles(appPath + "\\pdf2png").ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);
                    Directory.GetFiles(appPath + "\\png2text").ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                " Cought Exception in Generating image do{...}while{...} function " +
                Environment.NewLine + exception.Message + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    // Delete png image here
    Directory.GetFiles(appPath + "\\pdf2png").ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);
    Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout: 1000);
    // Read text from text file here
    foreach (var textFile in Directory.GetFiles(appPath + "\\png2text", "*.txt",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        loggingInfo += textFile +
                       " In Reading Text from generated text file by Tesseract " +
                       Environment.NewLine;
        strBldr.Append(File.ReadAllText(textFile));
    }
    // Delete text file after reading text here
    Directory.GetFiles(appPath + "\\png2text").ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);
} while (extractor.GetNextImage()); // Advance image enumeration...
```

Comment: setup can be made available on code.google.com Tesseract OCR open source engine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had all these worked except for the correct character recognition.

But you need to consider these few things:

- Use correct tessnet2 library
- use correct tessdata language version
- tessdata should be somewhere out of your application folder where you can put in full path in the init parameter. use `ocr.Init(@"c:\tessdata", "eng", true);`
- Debugging will cause you headache. Then you need to update your app.config
  use this. (I can't put the xml code here. give me your email i will email it to you)

hope that this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great working example project; [Tesseract OCR Sample (Visual Studio) with Leptonica Preprocessing](https://github.com/gulakov/tesseract-ocr-sample)
Tesseract OCR Sample (Visual Studio) with Leptonica Preprocessing

Tesseract OCR 3.02.02 API can be confusing, so this guides you through including the Tesseract and Leptonica dll into a Visual Studio C++ Project, and provides a sample file which takes an image path to preprocess and OCR. The preprocessing script in Leptonica converts the input image into black and white book-like text.

Setup

To include this in your own projects, you will need to reference the header files and lib and copy the tessdata folders and dlls.

Copy the tesseract-include folder to the root folder of your project. Now Click on your project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer, and go to Project>Properties.

VC++ Directories>Include Directories:

..\tesseract-include\tesseract;..\tesseract-include\leptonica;$(IncludePath)
C/C++>Preprocessor>Preprocessor Definitions:

_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
C/C++>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies:

..\tesseract-include\libtesseract302.lib;..\tesseract-include\liblept168.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
Now you can include headers in your project's file:

## include

## include

Now copy the two dll files in tesseract-include and the tessdata folder in Debug to the Output Directory of your project.

When you initialize tesseract, you need to specify the location of the parent folder (!important) of the tessdata folder if it is not already the current directory of your executable file. You can copy my script, which assumes tessdata is installed in the executable's folder.

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
api->Init("D:\tessdataParentFolder\", ...
Sample

You can compile the provided sample, which takes one command line argument of the image path to use. The preprocess() function uses Leptonica to create a black and white book-like copy of the image which makes tesseract work with 90% accuracy. The ocr() function shows the functionality of the Tesseract API to return a string output. The toClipboard() can be used to save text to clipboard on Windows. You can copy these into your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly this is an older question when Tesseract 3 was the version available, but it came up in my search results while looking for a related issue and the question, and other answers, highlight the still valid issue of the difficulty of actually getting Tesseract installed, let alone configuring it to work correctly.

There is a far simpler solution (and using the updated Tesseract 5 engine) which does all the work for you, in IronOcr.

(Disclaimer: I do work for Iron Software, though I feel that others can benefit from this information, particularly as it relates to the question of using [Tesseract OCR in C#](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/tutorials/c-sharp-tesseract-ocr/) which **IronOcr** excels at).

```
using IronOcr;
var Ocr = new IronTesseract(); // nothing to configure
Ocr.Configuration.WhiteListCharacters = "0123456789"; // If digit only
using (var Input = new OcrInput(@"example.tiff"))
{
OcrResult Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
foreach (var Page in Result.Pages)
{
    // Page object
    int PageNumber = Page.PageNumber;
    string PageText = Page.Text;
    int PageWordCount = Page.WordCount;
    // null if we dont set Ocr.Configuration.ReadBarCodes = true;
    OcrResult.Barcode[] Barcodes = Page.Barcodes;
    System.Drawing.Bitmap PageImage = Page.ToBitmap(Input);
    int PageWidth = Page.Width;
    int PageHeight = Page.Height;
    foreach (var Paragraph in Page.Paragraphs)
    {
        // Pages -> Paragraphs
        int ParagraphNumber = Paragraph.ParagraphNumber;
        String ParagraphText = Paragraph.Text;
        System.Drawing.Bitmap ParagraphImage = Paragraph.ToBitmap(Input);
        int ParagraphX_location = Paragraph.X;
        int ParagraphY_location = Paragraph.Y;
        int ParagraphWidth = Paragraph.Width;
        int ParagraphHeight = Paragraph.Height;
        double ParagraphOcrAccuracy = Paragraph.Confidence;
        OcrResult.TextFlow paragrapthText_direction = Paragraph.TextDirection;
        foreach (var Line in Paragraph.Lines)
        {
            // Pages -> Paragraphs -> Lines
            int LineNumber = Line.LineNumber;
            String LineText = Line.Text;
            System.Drawing.Bitmap LineImage = Line.ToBitmap(Input); ;
            int LineX_location = Line.X;
            int LineY_location = Line.Y;
            int LineWidth = Line.Width;
            int LineHeight = Line.Height;
            double LineOcrAccuracy = Line.Confidence;
            double LineSkew = Line.BaselineAngle;
            double LineOffset = Line.BaselineOffset;
            foreach (var Word in Line.Words)
            {
                // Pages -> Paragraphs -> Lines -> Words
                int WordNumber = Word.WordNumber;
                String WordText = Word.Text;
                System.Drawing.Image WordImage = Word.ToBitmap(Input);
                int WordX_location = Word.X;
                int WordY_location = Word.Y;
                int WordWidth = Word.Width;
                int WordHeight = Word.Height;
                double WordOcrAccuracy = Word.Confidence;
                if (Word.Font != null)
                {
                    // Word.Font is only set when using Tesseract Engine Modes rather than LTSM
                    String FontName = Word.Font.FontName;
                    double FontSize = Word.Font.FontSize;
                    bool IsBold = Word.Font.IsBold;
                    bool IsFixedWidth = Word.Font.IsFixedWidth;
                    bool IsItalic = Word.Font.IsItalic;
                    bool IsSerif = Word.Font.IsSerif;
                    bool IsUnderLined = Word.Font.IsUnderlined;
                    bool IsFancy = Word.Font.IsCaligraphic;
                }
                foreach (var Character in Word.Characters)
                {
                    // Pages -> Paragraphs -> Lines -> Words -> Characters
                    int CharacterNumber = Character.CharacterNumber;
                    String CharacterText = Character.Text;
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap CharacterImage = Character.ToBitmap(Input);
                    int CharacterX_location = Character.X;
                    int CharacterY_location = Character.Y;
                    int CharacterWidth = Character.Width;
                    int CharacterHeight = Character.Height;
                    double CharacterOcrAccuracy = Character.Confidence;
                    // Output alternative symbols choices and their probability.
                    // Very useful for spellchecking
                    OcrResult.Choice[] Choices = Character.Choices;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Confirmed - works