# Read .jpeg image text using c# and Tesseract

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

Im trying to read the text content of an image using Tesseract. Im using the following code for that.

```
try
{
    //long i;
    var image = new Bitmap(@"D:\Projects\Project Docs\Oasis\20180405T105834.618.jpeg");
    var ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
    //ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
    ocr.Init(@"D:\Projects\Project Docs\Oasis\", "eng", false);

    var result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
    foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word.Text);
        Console.Read();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{

    throw;
}
```

at the `ocr.Init(@"D:\Projects\Project Docs\Oasis\20180405T105834.618.jpeg",` "eng", false); the application breaking without any exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tesseract OCR simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598390/tesseract-ocr-simple-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ocr.Init(@"D:\Projects\Project Docs\Oasis\", "eng", false);
```

In the above line the path for int will be the path of tessdata inside the solution. I corrected the path for my application to
  `ocr.Init(@"D:\vijesh\My Projects\Tesseract_OCR-master\Tesseract_OCR-master\Content\tessdata", "eng", false)`;